# Anti mobile additcation App with React native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I like to create a mobile APP which stop using social medias after a given time.

How can I get the list of running social media apps with time in Android /IOS with React native ?

The App is still in the planing stage so I still not try any libraries

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, React Native does not offer this sort of functionality, your only solution for this (Android only) is to create a [Native Module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) that implements [AndroidUserStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager) API.

Please read [this medium post](https://proandroiddev.com/accessing-app-usage-history-in-android-79c3af861ccf), it will help you understand this topic quite well. This is for Android, unfortunately I have no idea how to do the same feature in IOS.

I hope this answer helps you.